# Accesing child class value from list

Tags: c#

There two classes
1) Parent Class has 3 fields *all classes have getters and setters

```
public class CellPhone
{
    private string Iemi;
    private string description;
    private decimal price;

    public CellPhone(){}

    public CellPhone(string Iemi, string Description, decimal Price)
    {
        this.Iemi = Iemi;
        this.description = Description;
        this.price = Price;
    }
```

2) the Child has 1 field, but inherits all frield from the parent class.

```
public class InDate : CellPhone
{
    private string inDate;

    public InDate(){}

    public InDate(string Iemi, string Description, string InDate,
        decimal Price):base( Iemi,  Description,  Price)
    {
        this.inDate = InDate;
    }
```

3) I use manage to write all data, and read date to memory (to a list)

```
 public partial class frmSellCellPhone : Form
{
    CellPhoneList newList = new CellPhoneList();

    public frmSellCellPhone()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }
    private void frmSellCellPhone_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        newList.Fill();
    }

    private void btnSale_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = cmbBox.SelectedIndex;

    }     

    private void SearchItemOnList()
    {
       foreach (CellPhone c in newList)
        {                
            if (c.IEMI == txtSearchIEMI.Text)
            {
                txtDesciption.Text = c.Description;
                txtInPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Price);
                txtInDate.Text = ""; //can't access inDate?
            }
        }
    }
```

The issue is when i try displaying, the date is not accessible.

I would appreicate if any suggestion is offered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not pasted your CellPhoneList class (or is it just a List ?), but surely it is using CellPhone instead of InDate.
Change your SearchItemOnList() to

```
private void SearchItemOnList()
{
   foreach (InDate c in newList)
    {                
        if (c.IEMI == txtSearchIEMI.Text)
        {
            txtDesciption.Text = c.Description;
            txtInPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Price);
            txtInDate.Text = ""; //can't access inDate?
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following method, you step through a list of `CellPhone`s. 
`CellPhone` doesn't have a inDate property.

```
private void SearchItemOnList() {
   foreach (CellPhone c in newList) {                
        if (c.IEMI == txtSearchIEMI.Text) {
            txtDesciption.Text = c.Description;
            txtInPrice.Text = Convert.ToString(c.Price);
            txtInDate.Text = ""; //can't access inDate?
        }
    }
}
```

You would need to step through a list of `InDate`s to get that value.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It worked, This community is the best :)